# z-index ignored on child elements of an animated container

Tags: css, css-animations

Referring to this sample:
https://codepen.io/jyloo/pen/KKwoLKB

I noticed when I have an animated container with animation-fill-mode set to forward, the absolute positioned child elements (popup) inside it doesn't display as expected, and it seems like their z-index is being ignored.

My animation:

```
.animate {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.animate.animate--from-bottom {      
  opacity: 0;
  animation: from-bottom 0.3s ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
}

@keyframes from-bottom {
  0% {transform: translateY(80px);opacity:0;}
  100% {transform: translateY(0px);opacity:1;}
}
```

My Child Element (popup)

```
.popup {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: calc(300px - 2rem);
}
```

If I remove the animation-fill-mode, the child elements display just fine.

Can anyone help me to understand this behavior and the workaround so that my child element (popup) can work find under and animated parent.

Comment: The positioned div and the "Hello World" div have different stacking contexts.

Answer (score 1):

you can the css property like below for 3rd div.

To make 2nd div's content visible on top, you can try setting 3rd's z-index to lower value.

```
.dv {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

demo - https://codepen.io/AB-DEV/pen/LYEdKPj.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add class to the parent `<div>` of popup.

suppose I have add class `have_popup` to the parent div of popup `<div class="card have_popup">`.

now apply css to that class as below:

```
.have_popup {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I hope this will works fine for you.

Thank you...